# How Can I Store The Correct Angles For My Fractal Tree Project?

Tags: python, recursion, tkinter, fractals

I want to generate a fractal tree using recursion. However the "branches" of the tree aren't being drawn at the correct angle (Each branch should be drawn coming off at 45 degrees to the branch below it). Is my maths wrong or is it my code?

I've gotten out a pad and pen and from what I can tell, just adding the angle once each time the function runs should give the right answer, however it gives the branches coming off at different degrees instead.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
import numpy as np


#GLOBAL VARIABLES
Width=1500
Height=1000

l=400
decay=0.67
linewidth=5

theta=np.pi/4


#DEFINITIONS

def drawobject(x,y,l,angle_r,angle_l,theta):


    x1r= x + l*np.sin(angle_r)
    y1r= y - l*np.cos(angle_r)

    x1l= x + l*np.sin(angle_l)
    y1l= y - l*np.cos(angle_l)

    canvas.create_line(x,y,x1r,y1r,width=0.01*l,fill="black")
    canvas.create_line(x,y,x1l,y1l,width=0.01*l,fill="black")

    angle_r+=theta
    angle_l-=theta

    if l>3:

        drawobject(x1r,y1r,decay*l,angle_r,angle_l,theta)
        drawobject(x1l,y1l,decay*l,angle_r,angle_l,theta)


#MAINBODY

root=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(width=Width, height=Height, bg="white")
canvas.pack()   
drawobject(Width/2,Height,l,np.pi/4,-np.pi/4,theta)
root.mainloop()
```

Each branch should shoot off at plus/minus theta to the branch below, however the second layer of branches is flat and the third layer comes off at a different angle entirely. I'm also open to any style critiques of my code as I'm quite new, all the best!

Comment: Thanks for such a prompt reply, I've updated the code to separate those variables but still no luck. I should add the results are difficult to describe and its not always twice theta as measured from a line straight upwards. I've edited my question to hopefully remove some confusion and also to show you how I've separated them.

Comment: Well, one thing I notice is that you're using the same r and l angles for both recursive calls.  But the left and right branches should have different angles.  For the first (right) call you want `angle_r + theta` and `angle_r - theta`.  For the second (left) you want `angle_l + theta` and `angle_l  - theta`.

Comment: Ah! Thats a very good point, It seems to be producing the correct shape now, just rotated theta degrees about its start, is it possible the left hand side of the tree is wrong but the right is correct?

Comment: EDIT: I changed a +theta to a -theta in the input to the function and this seemed to work, thank you for your help Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angles I was inputting when I called the function inside itself were the same, when they should have been two different angles as suggested by Tom Karzes. See our comments for more details.